# How to execute a php file into jquery without post and get method?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to program a custom contact content manager in HTML/CSS with PHP/mySQL/Jquery to make it dynamic.

I have my login form which send the $_REQUEST to my connection.php, when the auth is correct, I return json to my Jquery and when it is good, I use window.location.replace to redirect the user to the control panel.

When I'm on the index.php of the control panel, I want to check if the user's session_id is into my sql database and if it exceeded the expiration time.

I have my functions which check this and return the good value but I want to execute it and send the result to my jquery without using GET or POST method.

If I remember, you have

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",   //or GET method
dataType: "json",
url: $(this).attr('action'),
data: $(this).serialize(),
success: function({
}),
error: function({
})
});
```

But you must specify the element "data" no? can I use it without data and put "file.php" as url without POST or GET method?

I want to get into my success method the result of my php functions :
if the json return false, the user can access the page.
if the json return true, I will logout the user and redirect him to the login.php

I'm doing this system because I don't want anybody can access the control panel by writing the correct url or after 4 days.. I put an expiration time to one hour (for the moment) for anybody who login into the control panel and I check on all page that the expiration time isn't exceeded.

I saw that using 'window.location.replace' doesn't allow to return to the previous page.. has anyone a solution? I don't want to have an event to redirect the user, only redirect him to another url (my file.php) after a condition.

Currently, I use it to execute php without POST, GET method with $.ajax..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(function(){
                var ticket = '<? echo $tickets; ?>';

                console.log(ticket);

                if ( ticket === '' )
                    $(".new_ticket h2").after('<p>Aucun nouveau ticket.</p>');
                else
                {
                    console.log('else');
                    $(".new_ticket h2").after('<p>Il y a un ticket.</p>');
                }
            });
        });
```

I have a last question, when I write :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(function(){
        }
```

Is it directly executed by jquery when the DOM is ready? can I write mutliple '$(function(){}' in a file ?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on the false premise that the jQuery ajax functions require a `data` argument to be specified.

Comment: If you have multiple questions, then ask multiple questions. Don't throw them together in a single question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the problem with using POST or GET? It works perfectly fine.

Here foobar.php returns a json object with status in it. Change it to whatever your script return.

```
$.post('foobar.php', function(data) {
    if( data.status === false)  {
        //All good
    }else {
        //Redirect
        window.location.href = "http://newpagehere.com/file.php";
    }
});
```

With `window.location.href` you will be able to use the back and forward buttons.

And yes, when using `$(document).ready(function() { });` it runs when the DOM is ready.
http://api.jquery.com/ready/

One last thing is that I would not rely on Javascript here, I would do all checking with PHP instead when the user changes page. I would also handle the redirection there.